# How can I ignore or solve (expression "... eq null" is not supported) errors in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, cascadingdropdown

In Powerapps I have a canvas app filling a SharePoint list with data. In the app, I have a cascading dropdown which refers to an excel table (in SharePoint library).

As soon as I open the app I get an error for every cascading dropdown I have added (4 in my case). They all refer to the excel table column headers.

I've added an example of this error:

> The requested operation is invalid. Server Response: locations failed: Expression "Locationofdelivery eq null" is not supported. clientRequestId: 85f05674-3d6c-4646-bba0-49779cacd780

After deleting the messages (clicking the x) the app works fine. So my quickest solution would be to ignore the error. I would be fine with other solutions too. If I just can get the app working without the errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being posted. We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).